# how to deal with recurring payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

I am new to the paypal and intefrati it with asp. Net mvc. 
Can anyone plz guide which api should be used...??

I have downloaded merchant sdk and I have also seen the documentation but still not able to get what can be used among express checkout, pro, adaptive payment, etc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Express Checkout with Recurring Payments.  Specifically, that will consist of the following API calls:

- SetExpressCheckout - To get a token back from PayPal, and then redirect the user to PayPal.
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails - To obtain details about the buyer.  This is optional depending on how you setup your SEC request
- DoExpressCheckoutPayment - This would be used to finalize a regular (non-recurring) Express Checkout flow.
- CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile - This would be used to generate the profile using the tok you got back from SEC.

If you want to setup recurring payments with credit cards directly on your site you'll need Payments Pro with Recurring Billing, and then you would use the PayFlow API to set everything up.